# Unable to generate PDB files in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2005

For most assemblies, I'm able to generate their respective .pdb files. However, I've got one project that isn't generating their .pdb files.

I've made sure that it on debug mode and that the project's code is not being optimized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just for the record: you can create PDB files for optimized release builds as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Build` tab of the Project Properties window, there's an `Advanced...` button. There, You have a combo box called `Debug info`. Set your options there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensure that you've got both the Debug Information Format set in the C/C++ project properties (under General in VS2003, I think it's pretty much the same on most VS versions) and also set the linker to generate debugging info, which is a separate setting found under Linker/Debugging?

Both of those settings are normally turned on by default in a debug build but depending on how the configuration has been edited, it might be that either of them has been switched off.